# How to make a QMediaPlayer send a token in header

Tags: c++, qt, streaming, media

In order to acquire an access to remotely stored video, I need to send a user token in header of HTTP request. I am using `QMediaPlayer` to stream it.

```
m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
```

I tried to use `setRawHeader(QByteArray("Token"), QByteArray("123456"));`, on `QNetworkRequest` and feed it to my `QMediaPlayer`. No result.

```
QNetworkRequest testRequest(QUrl("http://urltovideo/playlist.m3u8"));
testRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Token"), QByteArray("123456"));
m_player->setMedia(testRequest);
```

I tried to put it in `QMediaContent` and than feed it to `QMediaPlayer`. Again, no result.

```
QNetworkRequest testRequest(QUrl("http://urltovideo/playlist.m3u8"));
testRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Token"), QByteArray("123456"));
QMediaContent testMediaContent(testRequest);
m_player->setMedia(testMediaContent);
```

Even if I add a query to the request, it have an effect only on first request of the `QMediaPlayer`, then it requests chunk, no result.

```
QUrl mediaUrl("http://urltovideo/playlist.m3u8");
QUrlQuery testQuery;
testQuery.addQueryItem("Token", "123456");
mediaUrl.setQuery(testQuery);
m_player->setMedia(mediaUrl);
```

In all examples the video plays as it should (if token verification disabled).

How can I do that? Maybe there is a way to amend this field after request was formed?